# How to check for EP divisional filings?

Tags: european, continuation, epo, divisional

In the US, continuation applications of a given application can be checked for in the "Continuity Data" tab in PAIR.

In the case of EPO, divisionals (the analogue of continuations) may be less common due to EPO renewal fees due from the parent's EP filing date (e.g. see [here](https://www.schleeip.com/patents-2/continuing-patent-application-uspto-epo/)).

I have not been able to find any examples of EP divisionals.  How can I determine whether one has been filed for a given application (e.g. via EP register or GPI)?  Is it possible to provide an example EP divisional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the EP register, there is a specific field called "Divisional application(s)". This is only shown where there is actually a divisional application.

An example of this can be seen on [EP 11749534](https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP11749534&tab=main). This shows EP 16178435 is a divisional.

If you want to find more divisionals generally, one approach is to search for an application having an application date significantly more than 18 months before the publication date. This typically only occurs for divisional applications, and this is how I found EP 16178435 above.

Answer (score 5):

And in addition to the above answer, you can check if a divisional has been filed but is **not yet published** at the "Event History" tab of the page Maca provided already. It displays a message reading "Change - divisional application(s)" and on the far right the date on which the filing of the divisional **will be** announced at the EP Bulletin. This is particularly useful if you are monitoring a really important patent application and want to be informed as quickly as possible.

Comment: Very good to know. I was actually meaning to check that exact point for my answer, but didn't quite get to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the INPADOC legal status code EP AC, e.g. in INPADOC on STN you would use EPAC/LSC to retrieve all divisional applications
Christoph (PATON, InPharmation)