How to find all the divisional applications of an EP?
I'm looking for the proper way to find all the divisional applications of an EP on the EPO register.
Maybe I'm mistaken, but I can't find it.
All I can read is : The date of the Examining Division's first communication in respect of the earliest application for which a communication has been issued is  XX.XX.XXXX
Any help would be much appreciated.
Serotonin

Do you have an example you of an application that has divisionals that you can provide?

I belive the same question has already been asked: https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/19540/how-to-check-for-ep-divisional-filings?rq=1

I believe the divisional applications is mentioned when there is one, I just do not understand that sentence (The date of the Examining Division's first communication in respect of the earliest application for which a communication has been issued is XX.XX.XXXX). Could you explain it to me? Thank you !
